# Stateless component returns `null` for shallow snapshot testings

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a stateless component.

I am matching the snapshot for unit tests.

But it returns `null`

## Spec

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';
import StatelessComponent from 'components/elements/StatelessComponent';


describe('<StatelessComponent />', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<StatelessComponent />);
  });

  it ('should render with default props', () => {
    expect(shallowToJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

## Component

```
export const StatelessComponent = () => (
  <div className={styles['container']}>
    <div className={styles['description']}>
      <FormattedMessage {...emailErrorInfo} />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

## Snapshot

```
exports[`<StatelessComponent /> should render with default props 1`] = `null`;
```

Comment: can you mark my answer as a correct answer if it worked for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting the Stateless component as a default solved the issue.

```
const StatelessComponent = () => (
  <div className={styles['container']}>
    <div className={styles['description']}>
      <FormattedMessage {...emailErrorInfo} />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default StatelessComponent
```

Answer (score 2):

import `StatelessComponent` like this, because its not a default export

```
import { StatelessComponent } from 'components/elements/StatelessComponent';
```